# Search Text in PDFs

Tags: javascript, search, pdf, google-custom-search

Is it possible to search text in PDFs using a [Google Custom Search](http://support.google.com/customsearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=72369)?

I thought it wasn't possible although apparently Google indexes the PDFs which means you can search them, right?

I thought it may have been possible using JavaScript although I don't think it could go search keywords within the PDF, could it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
"The text you look for" filetype:pdf
```